# Class property — filling by Extension method while the Property is null

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have:

```
public class NameClass
{
 public NameClass(){}
 string Name {get; set;}
 bool IsValid {get; set;}
}

public class Person
{
 public Person() {}
 public NameClass Name {get; set;}
}
```

an extension method:

```
public static void FillIt(this NameClass c, string name)
{
 if (c == null)
 {
  c = new NameClass();
 }
 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) == false)
 {
  c.IsValid = true;
 }
 c.Name = name;
}
```

then there is a void to create Person instance:

```
private void CreateMyPerson()
{
 Person p = new Person();
 p.Name.FillIt(txtName.Text);

 if (p.Name == null) Response.Write("Ooops, PROBLEM!");
 // checking for filled p.Name - IT IS STILL null - WHY?
}
```

Googling didn't help me, I'm not native english speaker, maybe i can't ask uncle Google well.

Using extension method to fill the property seemed to me the most elegant way to assign it a value, but **although in the extension method the "c" variable seems to be initialized and set fine, later when checking if p.Name is null - it turns that it is not set**...

Any clues?

Comment: Your code cannot work. The properties `Name` and `IsValid` in the class `NameClass` are not accessible by the method `FillIt`. I would suggest that you add public modifier to these properties.

Comment: Yes, they are accessible unless I missed some magic words on declarations. The whole example are just parts of longer code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`p.Name` is a reference type variable which points to `null`. Calling `FillIt` method copies value of `p.Name` (which is `null`) to reference variable `c`. So, in fact there is no link between variable `c` and `p.Name` and any kind of manipulation on variable `c` is local.

On the other hand, if `p.Name` is not `null` and refers to memory address, lets say `0x1111`, then calling extension method would copy that address to variable `c` and manipulation on `c` would affect `p.Name` also, since they both refer to same memory address.

Comment: Both answers your, @David made me understand more how the things are working, I set this answer as a solution because (sorry @David), I like it more - simpler to understand for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
c = new NameClass();
```

You're not assigning an instance of `NameClass` to the property on the `Person` object.  You're assigning it *to the local variable `c`*.  Once that assignment is made, that local variable no longer has anything to do with the reference to the property on the `Person` class.

If you always want `Name` to be initialized, do it in the `Person` constructor:

```
public Person()
{
    this.Name = new NameClass();
}
```

Then your extension method doesn't need to check for null in the first place:

```
public static void FillIt(this NameClass c, string name)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) == false)
    {
        c.IsValid = true;
    }
    c.Name = name;
}
```

Since `c` is never re-assigned in this version, it still points at the property on the `Person` object.

Though depending on what you're trying to accomplish here, do you even need this extension method at all?  If it's *required* that a `Person` has a name, you can require that on the `Person` constructor.  And/or on the `NameClass` constructor.

Initializing an object and then checking that it's valid is two steps, but requiring it to be valid when initializing it makes it only one step.  If an "invalid" object shouldn't be allowed, simply don't allow it.

Comment: The code in question is very simplified from the real one I am facing and the property Name shouldn't be initialized unless having useful content.
Thank you for explanation, probably I am going to create non-extension methods to do the assignment (when usefull content available) to the properties. I would mess up the code doing "do I have usefull content for this property?" check for all of about 20 properties.

So the final look'd be like: p.Name = GiveMeNameClassIfUsable(txtName.Text);